# How to access "first_name" permission with Facebook SDK 4+ and Parse

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform

How do I access the read permissions within the PFFacebookUtils login method? I've upgraded to Parse 1.7.3 and am using the ParseFacebookUtilsV4 framework as well. I updated the method to `loginInBackgroundWithReadPermissions()` and below I have the following code:

```
// Login through Facebook IBAction
PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions, (appUser: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if let appUser = appUser {
        let request = FBRequest.requestForMe()
        request.startWithCompletionHandler { (request, user, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // Get Facebook user's "first_name" and set it to the newly created PFUser's "name" variable
            var name = user.objectForKey("first_name") as! String
            appUser["name"] = name
            appUser.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            })
        }
    }
})
```

I'm getting a compile-time error on `FBRequest.requestForMe()` saying

> Use of unresolved identifier 'FBRequest'

What should I be replacing this with so that I can access the "first_name" property of the Facebook user and set it to the Parse user's "name" property I have set up?

Answer (score 0):

Have you imported the Facebook SDK in your project? When you use the Parse utils, you still need to import/link it.

Also; what version of the SDK are you using? The `FBRequest` class is part of the 3.x series; I would advise to use the latest SDK which is in the 4.x version numbers now. Please make sure that the Parse Framework version you use matches the iOS framework used.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `FBRequest`, you now use the `FBSDKGraphRequest`. To sure to `import FBSDKCoreKit`. See Parse's tutorial on github for an example request.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-iOS/wiki/Integrate-Login-with-Facebook